# esri dynamic service is not visible on google map

Tags: google-maps, dynamic, service, arcgis

About 3 weeks ago the arcgis Dynamic service is no longer visible on the google map. At the beginning I thought that something went wrong with my code, but after executing a sample code that does the same with the same result, I realized that something else went wrong.
The following code was taken from "ArcGIS Server Link for Google Maps API V3: Examples". It is basically loading an ESRI sample dynamic service.
When I load a Dynamic service from my arcgis server, the service is loaded but its not visible on the google map. (I know that because when I click on the map I get the property window of the feature from the Dynamic service although it is not visible).

If you run the following code you will not be able to see the esri dynamic service:
http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer][1]'.
My question is what went wrong here?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Dynamic Map Service Overlay</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //copy from http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/versionchecker.html?v=2.86
        function getURLParam(name) {
          var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
          var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
          var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
          return (results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1]));
        }
        var gmaps_v = getURLParam('v');
        if (gmaps_v) gmaps_v = '&v='+gmaps_v;
        var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' + gmaps_v + '"></' + 'script>';
        document.write(script);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/arcgislink.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dynamap.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    </div>
</body>
```

```
//dynamap.js
function init() {
var myOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),//35.23, -80.84),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
streetViewControl: true //my favorite feature in V3!
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
myOptions);
var url = 
'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/
rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_C
ensus_USA/MapServer';

var url = 
'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS 
/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer';
var dynamap = new gmaps.ags.MapOverlay(url);
dynamap.setMap(map);    
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Perhaps try the [release version (v=3)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions), a lot of things broke with the latest experimental release (v=3.exp or no version specified)

Comment: Great accurate answer. THX. All I did was change the API version back to the release version, which is now 3.31
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.31& key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">script>-